# Exception: The parameters don't match the method signature for ContactsApp.createContact

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]

[image]

I want to create an automated process to convert google forms spreadsheet customer data to google contacts. I am not sure which string is it referring to that does not match the signature for ContactsApp.createContact.

I get an error saying:

> Exception: The parameters (String,String,String,String) don't match the method signature for ContactsApp.createContact.
> addContact  @ Google Contacts.gs:114

When I tried to implement a trigger upon completion of the form to automatically add the contacts in google contacts, it only shows the First Name, Last Name, Email, **BUT NOT THE PHONE**.

**Section of code that has error**

```
function addContact()
{
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
    var active_row = cell.getRow();
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  
    var first_name = range.getCell(active_row ,1).getValue();
    var last_name = range.getCell(active_row ,2).getValue();
    var email = range.getCell(active_row,3).getValue();
    var phone = range.getCell(active_row,4).getValue();  
    
    var contact = ContactsApp.createContact(first_name, last_name, email, phone);   (LINE 114)
    
    var mainGroup = ContactsApp.getContactGroup("System Group: My Contacts");
    
    mainGroup.addContact(contact);
 
  
    showOutputBox('first name' + first_name + '\nlast name' + last_name + '\nemail' + email + '\nphone' + phone, "added contact");
  
}
```

**This is the full code**

```
// Add a menu
// Adds a menu item Contacts → add Contact
// Add a handler to handle when you click on that menu item.

function onOpen() 
{
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Contacts')
      .addItem('add Contact', 'addContact')
      .addToUi();
}

function formSubmitted(e){

  addContact(e.namedValues);
}



// Add a contact from the Google sheet
// Picks up the contact from the currently selected cell.
// Google Sheet, first column First name, second column last name and third column email.
// Pick the values and call ContactsApp.createContact()


function addContact()
{
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
    var active_row = cell.getRow();
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  
    var first_name = range.getCell(active_row ,1).getValue();
    var last_name = range.getCell(active_row ,2).getValue();
    var email = range.getCell(active_row,3).getValue();
    var phone = range.getCell(active_row,4).getValue();  
    
    var contact = ContactsApp.createContact(first_name, last_name, email, phone);
    
    
    showOutputBox('first name' + first_name + '\nlast name' + last_name + '\nemail' + email + '\nphone' + phone, "added contact");
  
}

function showOutputBox(str, title)
{
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<pre>'+str+'</pre>')
    .setWidth(400)
    .setHeight(300);
  
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
    .showModalDialog(html, title);
}



// Where is the new contact?
// If you open contacts.google.com you still will not see the new contact yet. There was no error too. So where did the new contact disappear?
// The reason is that the new contact is not a member of any of your contact groups. There are predefined groups called “system groups” in every account.
// Let us first add a function to list all the groups.

function showContactGroups() 
{
  var groups = ContactsApp.getContactGroups();
  var str ='Groups\n';
  for(var g = 0; g < groups.length; g++) 
  {
    str +='\n'+groups[g].getName()
    
  }
  
  showOutputBox(str,'Your Contact Groups');
}




// Add a menu item to show the contact groups:
// Now your Contacts menu should have tow items. Select Contacts → show Groups.
// Show all the contact groups in your account

function onOpen() 
{
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Contacts')
      .addItem('show Groups', 'showContactGroups')
      .addItem('add Contact', 'addContact')
      .addToUi();
}



// Let us add your new contacts to “My Contacts” group.
// Updated code:

function addContact()
{
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
    var active_row = cell.getRow();
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  
    var first_name = range.getCell(active_row ,1).getValue();
    var last_name = range.getCell(active_row ,2).getValue();
    var email = range.getCell(active_row,3).getValue();
    var phone = range.getCell(active_row,4).getValue();  
    
    var contact = ContactsApp.createContact(first_name, last_name, email, phone);
    
    var mainGroup = ContactsApp.getContactGroup("System Group: My Contacts");
    
    mainGroup.addContact(contact);
 
  
    showOutputBox('first name' + first_name + '\nlast name' + last_name + '\nemail' + email + '\nphone' + phone, "added contact");
  
}
```

Comment: Sorry its JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

[ContactsApp.createContact](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contacts-app#createcontactgivenname,-familyname,-email) only accepts three parameters: `givenName`, `familyName` and `email`. There's no `createContact` method that accepts four parameters. Hence the error you are getting.

#### Solution:

Enable the [Advanced People Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/people) in order to use [People API](https://developers.google.com/people) and create your contact via [people.createContact](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/createContact), which allows you to set the contact's phone number (as well as a bunch of other properties).

#### Code sample:

```
const optionalArgs = {
  personFields: "emailAddresses,names,phoneNumbers"
};
const resource = {
  "emailAddresses": [
    {
      "value": email
    }
  ],
  "names": [
    {
      "givenName": first_name,
      "familyName": last_name
    }
  ],
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "value": phone
    }
  ]
};
People.People.createContact(resource, optionalArgs);
```

Comment: @FreshFlowers Please consider accepting this answer by clicking the check mark button underneath the vote buttons: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235.