# Contact Import failed

Tags: google-apps-script

my script faild at import!
You can see the Data I try to give to: group.addContact(ContactsApp.createContact
Do I need to remove the " [ ] " from csvData ?

Thanks

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {
    
      var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('file.csv').next();
      Logger.log(file.getSize());
      Logger.log(file.getName());
      Logger.log(file.getDateCreated());
      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
      Logger.log(csvData[1].concat());
      group.addContact(ContactsApp.createContact(csvData[1]));
    }
```

Ausführungsprotokoll
13:11:14
Hinweis
Ausführung begonnen
13:11:14
Info
1624.0
13:11:14
Info
file.csv
13:11:14
Info
Fri Sep 17 07:28:25 GMT+02:00 2021
13:11:14
Info
[Anna Musterfrau, Anna, , Musterfrau, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , * myContacts, * Home, anna@musterfrau.de, Mobile, +491234567890, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ]

13:11:15
Fehler
ReferenceError: group is not defined
importCSVFromGoogleDrive
@ Code.gs:9

---

function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {

```
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('file.csv').next();
  Logger.log(file.getSize());
  Logger.log(file.getName());
  Logger.log(file.getDateCreated());
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  //Logger.log(csvData[1]);
  var contdata = csvData[1].toString();
  Logger.log(contdata);
  
  var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup("System Group: My Contacts");
  group.addContact(ContactsApp.createContact(condata));
```

}

14:00:41
Hinweis
Ausführung begonnen
14:00:41
Info
1624.0
14:00:41
Info
file.csv
14:00:41
Info
Fri Sep 17 07:28:25 GMT+02:00 2021
14:00:41
Info
Anna Musterfrau,Anna,,Musterfrau,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,* myContacts,* Home,anna@musterfrau.de,Mobile,+491234567890,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
14:00:41
Fehler
ReferenceError: condata is not defined
importCSVFromGoogleDrive
@ Code.gs:16

---

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {
    
      var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('file2.csv').next();
      Logger.log(file.getSize());
      Logger.log(file.getName());
      Logger.log(file.getDateCreated());
      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
      var contdata = csvData[1].toString();

      Logger.log(csvData[1]);

      var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup("System Group: My Contacts");
      //bla = contdata.toUpperCase();
      Logger.log(csvData[1].toString());
      group.addContact(ContactsApp.createContact(csvData[1].toString));
```

}

15:11:01
Hinweis
Ausführung begonnen
15:11:01
Info
67.0
15:11:01
Info
file2.csv
15:11:01
Info
Thu Sep 23 15:02:18 GMT+02:00 2021
15:11:01
Info
['Anna', 'Weizenkeim', 'anna@weizenkeim.privat']
15:11:01
Info
'Anna','Weizenkeim','anna@weizenkeim.privat'
15:11:02
Fehler
Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for ContactsApp.createContact.
importCSVFromGoogleDrive
@ Code.gs:15

Answer (score 0):

Well your `group` variable is never defined. You want to do something like:

```js
const group = ContactsApp.getContactGroupById(id);
```

Check the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contacts-app#getcontactgroupbyidid)

Comment: my fault forgot:   var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup("System Group: My Contacts");

Comment: see above, made a code change..... but did not work

Comment: Well now your `toString` doesn't have the parenthesis. You might want to start paying attention to what you're typing before you post here :). Also check out [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68054224/exception-the-parameters-dont-match-the-method-signature-for-contactsapp-creat)